# PDAL pipeline to import las info to postgresql/postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pipeline, pdal

I'm wanting to write all the data from an .las pointcloud file to a PostgreSQL/postgis database.

My pipeline file is as follows:

```
{
  "pipeline":[
    {
      "type":"readers.las",
      "filename":"F:\\Drive\\KAP\\KAP\\99.526\\pointclouds\\201406071257\\201406071257.las",
      "spatialreference":"EPSG:32635"
    },
    {
      "type":"filters.chipper",
      "capacity":600
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.pgpointcloud",
      "connection":"host='localhost' dbname='dbname' user='user' password='pw'",
      "schema":"pointcloud_99_526",
      "table":"pc_201406071257",
      "compression":"dimensional",
      "srid":"32635"
    }
  ]
}
```

This works fine, I've added `"output_dims":"X,Y,Z,RED,GREEN,BLUE"` to the writer.
`ST_AsEWKT(PC_EXPLODE(pa)::geometry)` returns `SRID=32635;POINT(580985.1431 4275315.1888 230.0292)`, no RGB data.

```
pdal info F:\Drive\KAP\KAP\99.526\pointclouds\201507130641\201507130641.las -p 0
```

returns:

```
{
  "filename": "F:\\Drive\\KAP\\KAP\\99.526\\pointclouds\\201507130641\\201507130641.las",
  "pdal_version": "1.8.0 (git-version: Release)",
  "points":
  {
    "point":
    {
      "Blue": 32639,
      "Classification": 0,
      "EdgeOfFlightLine": 0,
      "Green": 32639,
      "Intensity": 33667,
      "NumberOfReturns": 1,
      "PointId": 0,
      "PointSourceId": 1,
      "Red": 36237,
      "ReturnNumber": 1,
      "ScanAngleRank": 0,
      "ScanDirectionFlag": 1,
      "UserData": 0,
      "X": 580999.6718,
      "Y": 4275267.379,
      "Z": 193.3465
    }
  }
}
```

The colour values look like they are longint, I'd like to write all these values to the database.

Comment: Do you want to insert this data using "normal" postgres clients or via the api you described?

Comment: I want to use the pipeline route as described above, currently the point data comes in as a geom which is fine, but I also want columns for each of the other attributes, so all the data is stored in the database.

Comment: I see. In this case I cannot help you - I thought you might want to use psql to insert the data directly to the db, e.g. `.. ST_MakePoint((jsonstring->'X')::TEXT::NUMERIC,(jsonstring->'Y')::TEXT::NUMERIC,(jsonstring->'Z')::TEXT::NUMERIC, blue, green, red, .. `. Good luck:)